# remove option once is selected from many select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I've some selected input, that have the same options.

same class, different id for each select.

I've a function "onChange" event of each select, that give me the option selected.

How can I remove then this value from all the others select, without removing it where is selected, and how to revert it if is "de-selected".

many thanks

the code:
-if option two is selected, id like to remove it from all select but not where is selected-

```
[..........on same div....]

<select onchange="getval(this);" class="optionRisp form-control" id="select_1_1" style="">
   <option value="">choose one node or leaf</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select onchange="getval(this);" class="optionRisp form-control" id="select_2_1" style="">
   <option value="">choose one node or leaf</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
[..........on others div....]

<select onchange="getval(this);" class="optionRisp form-control" id="select_1_2" style="">
   <option value="">choose one node or leaf</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<scirp>
 function getval(sel)
        {
            //remove option from list due selection
          //sel is the element just selected!
        }

</scirp>
```

Comment: Well...please show use your code so we can be able to help.

Comment: ok sorry I was thinking that is a generic problem...

Comment: You can make use of javasciprt $this and use that to change all others except the one that has just been clicked. Would need to see code to tell you how to implement though.

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: yes im using it in the same page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get all the selected values and store it on an array. Then you can use `filter` to hide those in array using `includes`

And i used jQuery `$("select").change(..` coz it easier. :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on('change', '.optionRisp', function() {
    var val = [];

    //Get all selected
    $('.optionRisp option:selected').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() != "") val.push($(this).val());
    });

    //Hide Selected
    if ( $(this).val() != "" ) {
      $(".optionRisp").not(this).find("option").show().filter(function() {
         return $(this).val() != "" && val.includes($(this).val()) ? true : false;
      }).hide();
    } else {
      $(".optionRisp").find("option").show().filter(function() {
         return $(this).val() != "" && val.includes($(this).val()) ? true : false;
      }).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="optionRisp form-control">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select class="optionRisp form-control">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select class="optionRisp form-control">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i see your snippet code works...mine no... it not enter into $(".optionRisp").change(function()

Comment: Can you create a www.jsfiddle.com on what you have so far?

Comment: no, sorry check the edit comentt... the code is so messy because is a blade template file... and ive not all components aviable then... ps the option are added dynamically

Comment: Can you use `$("body").on('change', '.optionRisp', function() {`?

Comment: yessssssssss its works! thanks a lot u save me from a nigthmare started long hours ago lol

Comment: Happy to help @JahStation :)